# How to transpose a multidimensional multi-file upload submission and maintain associative keys?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, file-upload, transpose

I have the following form that when sending multiple images generates a multidimensional array with all the data ordered by default.

**Form HTML and PHP:**

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="POST">
            <input name="image[]" type="file" multiple />
            <input type="submit" name="send" value="Send" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Sending it generates an array like this:**

```
$file1 = array(
    'imagen' => array(
        'name'      => array(
            'Image_name',
            'Image_name'
        ),
        'type'      => array(
            'jpg',
            'jpg'
        ),
        'tmp_name'  => array(
            'jpg',
            'jpg'
        ),
        'error'     => array(
            0,
            0
        ),
        'size'      => array(
            '200',
            '200'
        )
    )
);
```

I need to restructure this array in a simpler way so that the respective image values are together.

**Expected output:**

```
$file2 = array(
    array(
        'name' => 'Image_name',
        'type' => 'jpg',
        'tmp_name' => 'jpg',
        'error' => 0,
        'size' => 200
    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'Image_name',
        'type' => 'jpg',
        'tmp_name' => 'jpg',
        'error' => 0,
        'size' => 200
    )
);
```

Answer (score 4):

This task is about "transposing" an array and maintaining associative keys.

Three years later, I have decided to overhaul/rewrite this answer because the coding standard was much lower than I now tolerate and there was generally too much noise.  There are only two ways that I would perform this task on one of my own projects.  Both provide the same (desired) result; it is only a matter of coding style that divides them.

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/jtanO)

```
$POST = [
    'image' => [
        'name' => ['Image_name1', 'Image_name2'],
        'type' => ['jpg', 'png'],
        'tmp_name' =>['jpg', 'png'],
        'error'    => [0, 0],
        'size'     => ['200', '300']
    ]
];
```

Functional Programming:

```
$keys = array_keys($POST['image']);
var_export(
    array_map(
        function(...$col) use ($keys) {
            return array_combine($keys, $col);
        },
        ...array_values($POST['image'])
    )
);
```

Language Construct Syntax:

```
foreach ($POST['image'] as $key => $entries) {
    foreach ($entries as $index => $entry) {
        $result[$index][$key] = $entry;
    }
}
var_export($result);
```

Comment: I have done the same thing few months ago and I used the double `foreach` exactly as you have shown at the end. It is the easiest and cleanest solution. These 5 lines of code are all that you need.

Answer (score 2):

t's the expected output for default php functionality..however you can write custom function to sanitizer the array in form you want like below :

```
<?php

function reArrayFiles(&$file_post) {

    $file_ary = array();
    $file_count = count($file_post['name']);
    $file_keys = array_keys($file_post);

    for ($i=0; $i<$file_count; $i++) {
        foreach ($file_keys as $key) {
            $file_ary[$i][$key] = $file_post[$key][$i];
        }
    }

    return $file_ary;
}

?>
Then u can do the following:

<?php

if ($_FILES['upload']) {
    $file_ary = reArrayFiles($_FILES['ufile']);

    foreach ($file_ary as $file) {
        print 'File Name: ' . $file['name'];
        print 'File Type: ' . $file['type'];
        print 'File Size: ' . $file['size'];
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This simple `foreach` loop will help you out.

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/788917)

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$file1 = array(
    'imagen' => array(
        'name'      => array(
            'Image_name',
            'Image_name'
        ),
        'type'      => array(
            'jpg',
            'jpg'
        ),
        'tmp_name'  => array(
            'jpg',
            'jpg'
        ),
        'error'     => array(
            0,
            0
        ),
        'size'      => array(
            '200',
            '200'
        )
    )
);

$result=array();
foreach ($file1["imagen"] as $key => $value)
{
    foreach(range(0,count($value)-1)  as $index)
    {
        $result[$index][$key]=$value[$index];   
    }
}
print_r($result);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Image_name
            [type] => jpg
            [tmp_name] => jpg
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 200
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Image_name
            [type] => jpg
            [tmp_name] => jpg
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 200
        )

)
```

Comment: How can I generate the values that you manually set [0]? In this part of the code, $result["imagen"][0][$key]=$value[0];, if it is many images, can we improve that and make it automatic?

Comment: @Learningandsharing yaah sure, let me update your post for that as well.

Comment: @Learningandsharing I have updated my post, and you can check this https://eval.in/788922 for a bigger example..

Answer (score 0):

I am very grateful to all the users who contributed their knowledge in this post, they have helped me a lot. I will make one more contribution, with a way to do it. Here are the codes.

**Method #1:**

```
<?php 

$files = array(
    'imagen' => array(
        'name' => array(
            'Image_name',
            'Image_name'
        ),
        'type' => array(
            'jpg',
            'jpg'
        ),
        'tmp_name' => array(
            'jpg',
            'jpg'
        ),
        'error' => array(
            0,
            0
        ),
        'size' => array(
            '200',
            '200'
        )
    )
);


function normalize_files_array($files = []) {

    $normalized_array = [];

    foreach($files as $index => $file) {

        if (!is_array($file['name'])) {
            $normalized_array[$index][] = $file;
            continue;
        }

        foreach($file['name'] as $idx => $name) {
            $normalized_array[$index][$idx] = [
                'name'      => $name,
                'type'      => $file['type'][$idx],
                'tmp_name'  => $file['tmp_name'][$idx],
                'error'     => $file['error'][$idx],
                'size'      => $file['size'][$idx]
            ];
        }

    }
    return $normalized_array;
}

echo "<pre>"; print_r(normalize_files_array($files));

?>
```

**Result #1:**

```
Array (
    [imagen] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Image_name
                    [type] => jpg
                    [tmp_name] => jpg
                    [error] => 0
                    [size] => 200
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Image_name
                    [type] => jpg
                    [tmp_name] => jpg
                    [error] => 0
                    [size] => 200
                )
        )
)
```

**Method #2:**

```
$file1 = array(
    'imagen' => array(
        'name'      => array(
            'Image_name',
            'Image_name'
        ),
        'type'      => array(
            'jpg',
            'jpg'
        ),
        'tmp_name'  => array(
            'jpg',
            'jpg'
        ),
        'error'     => array(
            0,
            0
        ),
        'size'      => array(
            '200',
            '200'
        )
    )
);

$array = array_map(null, $file1['imagen']['name'], $file1['imagen']['type'], $file1['imagen']['tmp_name'], $file1['imagen']['error'], $file1['imagen']['size']);

echo "<pre>"; print_r($array);
```

**Result #2:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Image_name
            [1] => jpg
            [2] => jpg
            [3] => 0
            [4] => 200
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Image_name
            [1] => jpg
            [2] => jpg
            [3] => 0
            [4] => 200
        )

)
```

**Method #3**

```
<?php

$file1 = array(
    'imagen' => array(
        'name'      => array(
            'Image_name',
            'Image_name'
        ),
        'type'      => array(
            'jpg',
            'jpg'
        ),
        'tmp_name'  => array(
            'jpg',
            'jpg'
        ),
        'error'     => array(
            0,
            0
        ),
        'size'      => array(
            '200',
            '200'
        )
    )
);


function array_map_key($name, $type, $tmp_name, $error, $size){
        $tmp_array['name']  = $name;
        $tmp_array['type']  = $type;
        $tmp_array['tmp_name'] = $tmp_name;
        $tmp_array['error']     = $error;
        $tmp_array['size']  = $size;
        return $tmp_array;
}

$array = array_map('array_map_key', $file1['imagen']['name'], $file1['imagen']['type'], $file1['imagen']['tmp_name'], $file1['imagen']['error'], $file1['imagen']['size']);


echo "<pre>"; print_r($array);

?>
```

**Result #3:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Image_name
            [type] => jpg
            [tmp_name] => jpg
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 200
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Image_name
            [type] => jpg
            [tmp_name] => jpg
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 200
        )

)
```